# jquery mobile change transition of a specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a index.html. In this side are all sites. 
Now in my javascript file I have defined that the `dafaultPageTransition = "slide"`.
I have made a popup and changed the transition to pop. That it pop's out with `data-transition="pop"`, but it still slides.

**javascritp**

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    // settings
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
});
```

**html**

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-transition="pop" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="plus"></a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <h1>Add your Pattern</h1>
    <input type="text" alt="pattern" placeholder="Your Pattern">
</div>
```

Could anyone helps me?

Comment: You can open the popup programmatically, http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7KF3b/

Comment: yes, but it slides... idk what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: have you tried the code in the demo?

Comment: @Omar yes copy and paste.. but it slides

Comment: remove `data-transition` from popup div. you also have them duplicated. remove them all.

Comment: doesn't works... with your code and my

Comment: @Omar pls join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33349/jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

In doc: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/

By default, popups have no transition to make them open as quickly as possible. To set the transition used for a popup, add the data-transition attribute to the link that references the popup. The reverse version of the transition will be used when closing the popup.

```
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="flip" data-rel="popup">
   Flip transition
</a>
```

In your HTML the tag data-transition is duplicated. Can this be the problem?